# Why are latest dlls not available for direct download

Tags: servicestack

I used to download servicestack dlls from https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/downloads.

Why are latest dlls not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading DLLs is a bad idea.

Instead, you should simply use NuGet, which will automatically install the latest version and all of its dependencies.

Comment: We are using servicestack as part of our solution and all of the developers are supposed to use the same version of dlls. For that reason we put a copy of dll on our source control and reference it from there. The simplest way to do it was by downloading it from the documentation page. I will create a dummy project to download it via NuGet, but that was not necessary in the past.

Comment: @Tester NuGet will include the DLL in source control by default (unless you enable Package Restore).  I **highly** recommend that you switch to NuGet for all external projects; it's far easier to manage.

Comment: @Tester GitHub has stopped letting us upload new dlls and will remove the downloads page entirely in future. There are some manual instructions of extracting dlls from NuGet packages on the [OrmLite home page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#download-published-nuget-binaries-without-nuget)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :) It was not clear to me why the newer dlls were not there, now I know why :)